# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'instance' Python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, instance, calculator

I am trying to use Tkinterface to make a simple calculator, that adds, subtracts, multiplies and divides, but I have a issue, when I try to execute my program, i get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'instance'

I have personally no idea why this is happening, I have been looking around, and have found issues with similar errors, but not with "instance" and "instance".
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

#Imports necessary modules

from Tkinter import *
#import Tkinter.messagebox
import time as t
import os

#End of importing

#Defines interface

calc = Tk()
calc.title("GUI Calculator")
calc.geometry("500x350+200+200")

#End of interface definition

#Defines methods

def add(val1, val2):
    global ans
    ans = int(val1 + val2)
    return ans

def sub(val1, val2):
    global ans
    ans = int(val1 - val2)
    return ans

def mul(val1, val2):
    global ans
    ans = int(val1 * val2)
    return ans

def div(val1, val2):
    global ans
    ans = float(val1 % val2)
    return ans

#End of method defining

#Heading
but1Text = StringVar()
but1Text.set("Welcome to the GUI Calculator")
label1 = Label(calc, textvariable=but1Text, height=2)
label1.pack()

#Instruction 1
but2Text = StringVar()
but2Text.set("Enter value number one!")
label2 = Label(calc, textvariable=but2Text, height=2)
label2.pack()

#Val 1 input
num1 = IntVar()
val1 = Entry(calc, textvariable=num1)
val1.pack()

#Instruction 2
but3Text = StringVar()
but3Text.set("Enter value number one!")
label3 = Label(calc, textvariable=but2Text, height=2)
label3.pack()

#Val 2 input
num2 = IntVar()
val2 = Entry(calc, textvariable=num2)
val2.pack()

#Operation selector

but4Text = StringVar()
but4Text.set(None)
operator = Radiobutton(calc, text = "Addition", value = "Add", variable = but4Text,command = add(val1,val2)).pack()
operator = Radiobutton(calc, text = "Subtract", value = "Sub", variable = but4Text,command = sub(val1,val2)).pack()
operator = Radiobutton(calc, text = "Multiply", value = "Mul", variable = but4Text,command = mul(val1,val2)).pack()
operator = Radiobutton(calc, text = "Divide",   value = "Div", variable = but4Text,command = div(val1,val2)).pack()

#Answer
but5Text = StringVar()
but5Text.set("Answer=")
label4 = Label(calc, textvariable=but5Text, height=2)
label4.pack()

#Answer
but6Text = StringVar()
but6Text.set(ans)
label5 = Label(calc, textvariable=but6Text, height=2)
label5.pack()

#Mainloop
calc.mainloop()
```

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tkCalc.py", line 76, in <module>
    operator = Radiobutton(calc, text = "Addition", value = "Add", variable = but4Text,command = add(val1,val2)).pack()
  File "./tkCalc.py", line 24, in add
    ans = int(val1 + val2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'instance'
```

Comment: please provide the full traceback

Comment: `val1` and `val2` are Entry objects. Why do you expect `val1 + val2` to work?

Comment: I want the user to input 2 values, and use them as numbers for the calculator

Comment: The full traceback has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform your operations on the numeric value, (int or float), of the text in the control instances, rather than the controls themselves.

Try:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    global ans
    ans = int(num1.get() + num2.get())
    return ans
```

and

```
operator = Radiobutton(calc, text = "Addition", value = "Add", variable = but4Text,command = add(num1, num2)).pack()
```

So your add button passes the variables and the function gets the values from them.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am semi-new Python, so could you please explain to me what I would change?

Comment: @Hansmoehansen expanded the answer.

Comment: I have changed my code around, and it launches, but how would I get the output from the method / function, would I just do it as I have it the code already or should I change it? (The way I do it already, the display on the interface does not update)